# In C# on windows phone Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode)

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream("MyFolder\\MyFile.txt", FileMode.Open);
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyFolder\\MyFile.txt", FileMode.Append, myIsolatedStorage));

    using (writeFile)
    {
        FS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        writeFile.WriteLine(txtWrite.Text);
        writeFile.Close();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Now I am here");
    }
```

When I am trying to run this code(trying to append data into an existing text file), getting exception

> "Attempt to access the method failed:
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode)"

What is the mistake I have done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it working after struggling for 4 hrs:

```
 IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();                
            StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyFolder\\MyFile.txt", FileMode.Append, myIsolatedStorage));

            writeFile.Flush();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(txtWrite.Text);
            writeFile.WriteLine(txtWrite.Text);                
            writeFile.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Now I am here");
```

I removed the file stream method and did some modifications. Its started to work.
Thanks to everybody who tried to help me with your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `FileStream` class directory. Get your streams via the methods on [`IsolatedStorageFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile_methods):

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = 
    IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var writeFile = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("MyFolder\\MyFile.txt", FileMode.Append))
using (var writeFileStream = new StreamWriter(writeFile))
{
    writeFileStream.WriteLine(txtWrite.Text);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Now I am here");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. It works but it will NOT APPEND the data to the existing text file instead its overrides it.

Comment: @SankarGuda You have to open the file with FileMode.Append

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're attempting to open the same file twice?

A version of your question (with an answer) can be seen at [How to append data into the same file in IsolatedStorage for Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227836/how-to-append-data-into-the-same-file-in-isolatedstorage-for-windows-phone)

Comment: It looks like it's a _method_ access error, not a _file_ access error.

Comment: @RichardSzalay, yeah.It is the exception regarding accessing this method: FS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);