# There is an error in XML document(1.1)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

The error occurs when I try to deserialize the stream.

```
public static AllFlags Load()
{
    IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    AllFlags allFlags;

    //IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open);
    StringReader stream = new StringReader(filename);
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllFlags));
    allFlags = xml.Deserialize(stream) as AllFlags;// here There is an error in XML
    stream.Close();
    stream.Dispose();

    return allFlags;
}
```

If I open the file from isolated storage is no problem

```
public static AllFlags Load()
{
    IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    AllFlags allFlags;

    IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open);
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllFlags));
    allFlags = xml.Deserialize(stream) as AllFlags;
    stream.Close();
    stream.Dispose();

    return allFlags;
}
```

How can I open this file?

EDITED:

My xml file "Flags.xml":

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <AllFlags>
      <Flags>
        <Flag>
          <Tag>Tag1</Tag>
          <Name>Name1</Name>
        </Flag>

...

      </Flags>
    </AllFlags>
```

Comment: What does the xml look like?

Comment: Hmm.. have you checked the exception for inner exceptions? From what I remember this error contains more information than what the message says

Answer (score 0):

A [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.stringreader.aspx) doesn't read from a file, but from a string. You are parsing whatever is in `filename` as XML (which isn't XML, but a path).

You probably want to use a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx) instead:

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filename);
```

Comment: Now I get another error:
Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719100/in-c-sharp-on-windows-phone-attempt-to-access-the-method-failed-system-io-files I didn't notice your `windows-phone-7` tag. I guess `IsolatedStorage` is the way to go in your case.

Comment: When I use isolated storage I get error:
Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

I think it can not find the file.

Comment: @YaroslavShabanov euh... in your question you state it works when using `IsolatedStorageFileStream`.

Comment: Yes, it work if file in isolated storage. I mean, if first create and save the file in the isolated storage then it is open with no problems. But I have a file that I've put into the project and it is not in the isolated storage.

Comment: @YaroslavShabanov sorry can't help you further. I have no experience on Windows Phone or IsolatedStorage.