# How to append text in .txt file in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, file-io

I am trying to append some text in a .txt file and this .txt file is in the application directory(I mean, it is in the project solution).

Can I operate read/write operation in application directory files?

The code I am trying to append text is below:

```
StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("txtfile/settings.txt");
writer.WriteLine(addTask);
writer.Close();
```

but it is throwing error: 
$exception: "Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.File.AppendText(System.String)"

So how can I append text in the file which is in the project solution folder.

Comment: Do you need to change the file precisely in application directory? 'Cause the common solution for windows phone will be to copy that file to IsolatedStorage and work with it there. @vkwave?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C# on windows phone Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719100/in-c-sharp-on-windows-phone-attempt-to-access-the-method-failed-system-io-files)

Answer (score -1):

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Sample.txt"));
        using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
            var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outStream);
            string response = "SomeText";
            dataWriter.WriteString(response);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
            await outStream.FlushAsync();
            outStream.Dispose(); // 
            fs.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Yes @Cheese. The file is available

Comment: StorageFile is not for windows phone 7